# looping through variable post vars and adding them to the database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have been given the task of devising a custom forms manager that has a mysql backend.

The problem I have now encountered after setting up all the front end, is how to process a form that is dynamic.

For E.G

Form one could contain 6 fields all with different name attributes in the input tag.
Form two could contain 20 fields all with different name attributes in the input tag.

How would i process the forms without using up oodles of resource.

**Final Answer**

*Based on Accepted answer by Arda Xi*

```
function processForm($form_id) {

    $rows = "";
    $values = "";

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {

        $rows = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
        $values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        $entry .= "[".$rows . "::".$values."]";

    }
    // clean up the array


    $entry = preg_replace('/^\[|\d+|\:\:\]/', '', $entry);

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `forms_form_data` (`id`, `form_id`, `entry`, `manager_id`, `status`, `created_at`) VALUES (NULL, '".$form_id."', '".$entry."', '".$_SESSION['manager_id']."', '0', NOW())");

}
```

Comment: I'm looking at that regex you used, and I'm not sure if it'll do what you want. It will either remove the [ if the string starts with it, remove all digits or remove only `::]`. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally the only way would be using a loop. If you want to use as little resources as possible, you can concatenate them.

```
$columns = "";
$values = "";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $columns .= "`" . mysql_real_escape_string($key) . "`, ";
    $values .= "`" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "`, ";
}
$columns = substr($columns, 0, -2);
$values = substr($values, 0, -2);
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (".$colums.") VALUES (".$values.")";
```

This will create one query for all the values in the form.

Comment: looks good, however i forgot to mention the value of each post will only be going into one field in the destination table. how would i incorporate this into what you have said :)

Comment: So you want the entire form into one field? Like a comma-seperated value?

Comment: essentially, not so much csv as i have my own formatting but all the information submitted via the form will go into table `forms_form_data` row `entry`

Comment: Could you perhaps show me the code you're using or perhaps a function and what parameters it takes, so I can integrate it into the example above?

Comment: i don't have any functions for processing the form data yet. this is what the question is regards to. i'm not sure what your asking for.

Comment: Well, you must have some idea in what formatting you want for the entries. Knowing that format is necessary in order to write the code proper.

Comment: I've messed around with your code and got an answer as above.

Answer (score 1):

Why not store the serialized value of $_POST as is? Of course escaping it to make it database safe. Like:

```
$value=serialize($_POST);
```